# Elasticsearch: Bucket Sort Aggregation + Sorting on Alphabetical Field

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am trying to club data on field and that should be sorted on another field. I also want pagination so I thought I could use BucketSort of elasticsearch. I am facing a problem with the String(Alphabetical) Filed.

Here is my dummy data.

```
{
    "_index": "testing-aggregation",
    "_type": "employee",
    "_id": "emp001_local000000000000001",
    "_score": 10.0,
    "_source": {
        "name": [
            "Person 01"
        ],
        "groupbyid": [
            "group0001"
        ],
        "ranking": [
             "2.0"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_index": "testing-aggregation",
    "_type": "employee",
    "_id": "emp002_local000000000000001",
    "_score": 85146.375,
    "_source": {
        "name": [
            "Person 02"
        ],
        "groupbyid": [
            "group0001"
        ],
        "ranking": [
             "10.0"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_index": "testing-aggregation",
    "_type": "employee",
    "_id": "emp003_local000000000000001",
    "_score": 20.0,
    "_source": {
        "name": [
            "Person 03"
        ],
        "groupbyid": [
            "group0002"
        ],        
        "ranking": [
             "-1.0"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_index": "testing-aggregation",
    "_type": "employee",
    "_id": "emp004_local000000000000001",
    "_score": 5.0,
    "_source": {
        "name": [
            "Person 04"
        ],
        "groupbyid": [
            "group0002"
        ],
        "ranking": [
             "2.0"
        ]
    }
}
```

Mapping for the above data.

```
{
    "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fielddata": true,
        "fields": {
            "lower_case_sort": {
                "type": "text",
                "fielddata": true,
                "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
            }
        }
    },
   "ranking": {
         "type": "float"
    },
    "groupbyid": {
        "type": "text",
        "fielddata": true,
        "index": "analyzed",
        "fields": {
            "raw": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ES Query:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "name:XYZ"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "groupbyid": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "groupbyid.raw",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_hit_agg": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 100
          }
        },
        "ranking_agg": {
            "min": {
                "field": "ranking"
            }
        },
        "test_bucket_sort": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "ranking_agg": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 100,
            "from": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to achieve for the Numeric field. But do not have an idea how will I do for the name field. One way is to use the script, but I do not want to go with this approach as it might be an expensive operation.

Can anyone help me with this? I am using ES 7.7.1.

Thank you,
Sharvil Shah

Comment: Can you share your expected output?

Comment: Let's say if I wanted to club record on field groupbyid and sort on the name field by desc, the output will look like this. 

`group0002(emp003_local000000000000001,emp004_local000000000000001)`
`group0001(emp001_local000000000000001,emp002_local000000000000001`)`

Answer (score 2):

> If you want to sort `name` field alphabetically, then instead of
> `groupbyid` you can use `name.keyword` in terms aggregation and sort
> on the key.

**You cannot use the `name` field in min aggregation, as text fields are not supported for [Min aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-min-aggregation.html)**

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "groupbyname": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name.keyword",
        "order": { "_key" : "desc" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "groupbyname": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Person 04",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Person 03",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Person 01",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: In this, scenario, I also wanted to group the records. and also it will go to a club name whose value is the same. So I wanted a club based on groupbyid and sort the whole bucket based on the name field. I know it's a bit tricky but this is one of our use-cases.